# Window loaded and rendered event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Window with StackPanel inside. I need to add some random count of lines to this panel in ctor and then animate them.

But how can I catch the moment when window and panel is already rendered or else?

All I try fails because the panel does not exist; still or some of lines are "cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'".

What the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try to use this.Loaded += new Window_Loaded(...);

Comment: Of course.. Now I found out that the problem is maybe a little another - if I try to animate my lines on, for example, click on window (everything is completely rendered and showed) I still get error of "name" cannot be found on the name scope of stackPanel .. But I use exactly panel's objects...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solve this problem by setting in storiboard initialization method SetTarget instead of SetTargetName and now my animations are not dependent on object name!